# Like selected file name in PHP

Tags: php, move-uploaded-file

I have a file image with the name :

```
35210001.jpg
```

And I want to move the file to another folder.
What is the solution to handle the "LIKE" in PHP like Query in MySQL because the filename indicator obtained from the request to move is only :

```
3521
```

This is mycode :

```
$name = "35210001.jpg";
$date = date("YmdHis");
File::move('C:/xampp/htdocs/test/test_media/' . $name, public_path('test_move' . $date . '.jpg')); public_path('test_move' . $date . '.jpg'));
```

Comment: What are you talking about, "LIKE query"? Really unclear what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the glob function, [here is the doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php)

Exemple from doc :

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename occupe " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```